# Prevent WiFi from power off

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

*Backround: Android 2.x running on a Tablet.*
Is there any way to prevent the WiFi from power off when there are no connection incoming or outgoing? I need the WiFi to stay alive for incoming connection from a server. For now I am doing keep alive calls but that's not that nice. I've googled that already and found out that it is something about powersaving. Is there anyway to come around this?

Thanks in advance for any Help on this!

Comment: This only happens when you turn of screen right?

Comment: No. It alsways happens after some while. The screen is alsways on. I just change to a sort of screensaver after a idle time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to go to Settings -> Wireless -> Wifi Settings -> Menu -> Advanced -> WiFi Sleep Policy and change the policy.

This may avoid the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Ok, that worked! But I am still losing connectivity after some time. I think I will go to a new one for this with a better matching headline. Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: I observed that too. Even if the Wifi Sleep Policy in Settings is set to "Never", Wifi turns off exactly 15 minutes after the screen turns off (tested on Android 2.2). I suppose `WifiManager.WifiLock` is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try the WifiLock just like the WakeLock.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html