# Android loosing connection although the WiFi is still turned on

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

*Backround: Android 2.x on a tablet*
That a the second [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976469/prevent-wifi-from-power-off) on this. Now the WiFi don't get turned off by android but I although loose the connectivity after some, means the server can no longer reach the android device (I get a timeout). I tried this at least on four different tablets so I don't think that it depends on the hardware. A continous polling prevent this but this should be just a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lays in the wifi router AP (access point).  There is a value thats called TTL (time to live) which controls how long a connection is held open after last activity before closing from no activity. You need to change this value in the router.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense…